micro array image registration
How can I image-register these two images?


They are magnetic microdot arrays, at different magnetic fields.
Subtracting one from the other I should be able to discern a magnetic contrast.
after defining a contrast-stretching function:
def stretch(i,mt=2,Mt=98):
    minval = np.percentile(i, mt)
    maxval = np.percentile(i, Mt)
    imgsub = np.clip(i, minval, maxval)
    imgstretched = ((imgsub - minval) / (maxval - minval)) * 255
    return imgstretched

and cropping out the status bar:
imagesizey, imagesizex = imgsat.shape[:2] 
imgsat = imgsat[0:imagesizey-50, :] 
img = img[0:imagesizey-50, :] 

I tried SciKit:
from skimage.registration import phase_cross_correlation
from scipy.ndimage import fourier_shift
shift, error, diffphase = phase_cross_correlation(img, imgsat, upsample_factor=100)
offset_image = fourier_shift(np.fft.fftn(img), shift)
offset_image = np.fft.ifftn(offset_image)
plt.imshow(stretch(offset_image.real-imgsat,mt=2,Mt=98), cmap='gray')

I tried an image-registration package (https://image-registration.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):
from image_registration import chi2_shift
from image_registration.fft_tools import shift
import noise
xoff, yoff, exoff, eyoff = chi2_shift(img, imgsat,return_error=True, upsample_factor='auto')
corrected_image2 = shift.shiftnd(img, (-yoff, -xoff))
imgs = corrected_image2-imgsat
plt.imshow(stretch(imgs,mt=2,Mt=98), cmap="gray")

Last I tried PyStackReg
from pystackreg import StackReg
sr = StackReg(StackReg.TRANSLATION)
out_tra = sr.register_transform(imgsat, img)
plt.imshow(stretch(out_tra-imgsat,mt=2,Mt=98), cmap='gray')

In all cases the subtraction fails, with results similar to this (this with SciKit):

I might add that the array in the images drift, but some details, like the two black specks at the left, remain stable, being defects in the optics.
Can you suggest me some alternative?

Not sure what has happened here. You can perfectly align the two largest scratches on the left side and the text along the bottom, but when you do that the micro-dots are not optimally aligned. Maybe try trimming the left side and bottom off prior to registering and seeing if you can get the micro-dots aligned rather than the text and large scratches on the left?

An easy way to align the images, by the way, is to load both into Photoshop and paste one on top of the other. Then set the "Blending Mode" to "Difference" on the upper layer and then move either layer around one pixel at a time with arrow keys, and when they are aligned the image will be perfectly black all over because the difference will be zero.

opencv has ECC refinement. should work fine since your two objects are already mostly aligned.

Your input images have a black bar with text along the bottom, the result image does not. I don’t think you are showing everything you do. Please show how you read these images into Python and crop them. Or are the images you show here screen grabs from an image display?

Also, the contrast stretch is probably a bad idea. Have you tried it without that step?

sorry, to be brief I skipped the fact that the text bar was cropped in the two source images (I edited the question).

The contrast stretch is usually required to discern the very faint magnetooptic image inside the dots... without it you usually obtain an almost uniform result.

There are several things going on here. First of all, a lot of the artifacts we see in the image are caused by the camera, and therefore do not move from the one image to the other. There are dead (black) pixels and hot (white) pixels, and there's black corners that indicate the end of the field of view (likely dictated by a diaphragm or the lens itself). There is also a black bar with text along the bottom of the image, which I presume is overlaid by the imaging software.
So, to get a good alignment, we have to remove these artifacts as much as possible. I just cropped the edges off the images.
Next, we need to make sure we shift the images in the right direction. For example, in your first attempt, you used skimage.registration.phase_cross_correlation. Its documentation describes the output as:

Shift vector (in pixels) required to register moving_image with reference_image.

moving_image is the second input argument. So with the call phase_cross_correlation(img, imgsat, ...), it is imgsat that should be shifted by shift, not img as you do. So, that code increases the shift between the images instead of reducing it.
I wrote simple code using DIPlib (disclaimer: I'm an author) because I think it's a lot easier to use than all the other alternatives you tried:
import diplib as dip

img1 = dip.ImageRead("so_1.png")
img2 = dip.ImageRead("so_2.png")

img1_crop = img1[25:395, 25:225]  # remove edges of two images
img2_crop = img2[25:395, 25:225]

shift = dip.FindShift(img1_crop, img2_crop)
img1_shifted = dip.Shift(img1, shift)  # apply the shift to the full image

dip.viewer.ShowModal(img1_shifted - img2)  # show the difference


Note how the majority of the defects appear along the edges of the difference image, justifying our decision to crop those parts off to estimate the shift.
See the docs for dip.FindShift, it uses the "MTS" method by default, "ITER" is slower but more precise by about 6 orders of magnitude. You can also use three different forms of cross-correlation, those tend to be less precise.

Thank you! I see in your docs that FindShift works at sub-pixel resolution, and that's exactly what I need here. Not clear from the docs if also dip.Shift operates at sub-pixel ...

@alessandro yes, it does.
